# pipenv install fails when run inside a container

Tags: python, docker, pipenv

I want to use pipenv to run some tests that are dependent on a python package called airflow. Unfortunately when I try and install that package I get an error that I can't fathom out.

I've built a little demo of the problem using a docker container. Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-stretch

WORKDIR /tmp

# Define build args
ARG http_proxy
ARG https_proxy
ARG no_proxy

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install default-jdk

# Detect JAVA_HOME and export in bashrc.
# This will result in something like this being added to /etc/bash.bashrc
#   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
RUN echo export JAVA_HOME="$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:/jre/bin/java::")" >> /etc/bash.bashrc

# Upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# Install core python packages
RUN pip install pipenv
```

I build the image and run the container using:
`docker build -t pipenvtest .`
`docker run -it pipenvtest bash`

Once connected to the container I run:
`pipenv --python 2.7`
`pipenv install --dev airflow`

Which fails with this error:

> Installing airflow...
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/local/bin/pipenv", line 11, in 
>       sys.exit(cli())
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 722, in **call**
>      return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 697, in main
>      rv = self.invoke(ctx)
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
>      return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
>      return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
>      return callback(*args, **kwargs)
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 435, in install
>       selective_upgrade=selective_upgrade,
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1971, in do_install
>      pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1375, in pip_install
>      package_name.split('--hash')[0].split('--trusted-host')[0]
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/models/requirements.py", line 704, in from_line
>      line, extras = _strip_extras(line)
>   TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

What's strange is that I can successfully install `airflow` on my local machine but when i try and do it in this container, it fails. I need to get it working in the container because we run our CI tests inside containers.

I'm hoping someone can diagnose why this isn't working. I suspect there's a problem with the container image, but I haven't a clue what it might be.

Comment: You still appear to be using Python3.6 environment in the container. This may be the issue since it appears you wanted a Python 2.7 environment.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in pipenv involving the new version of pip: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2924

Comment: @mrunion good spot. Haven't a clue why that is. WiIl investigate.

Comment: @jwodder thank you very much, that does certainly seem to be the problem (and is the second problem with pip/pipenv I've experienced in a couple of hours :( )

Comment: I ran into this issue today. You have to make sure your pip inside and outside pipenv environment are both 18.0 and not 18.1. I didn't realize that it was both.

Comment: Yes you need to do this https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2924#issuecomment-427351356